# How do you stretch header, content & footer color across a page with everything being centered in a fixed width?

Tags: html, css

I have got the header and main page content color to stretch the full page but still have the content centered.

However my footer isn't stretched, how do I stretch the footer like the header?

**HTML:**

```
<body> 
<div id="header"> 
    <div class="container"> <img src=   "images/webalign-uk-white.png" width="429" height="61" />
        <!-- header's content here --><p class="fltrt">Contact: 00000000000</p></div>
    <!-- .container --> 
</div><!-- #header --> 
<div id="content"> 
    <div class="container"> 
        <!-- main content here --><h1> Hello!</h1>

 <div id="footer">
    <div class="container"> 
        <!-- footer's content here --><p>Footer1</p>
  </div><!-- .container --> 
</div><!-- #footer --> 
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 15px; /* the auto value on the sides, coupled with the width, centers the layout */
}

#header {
    background-color: #eee;
}

#content {
    padding: 10px 0;
    background-color:#F9f9f9;
}

#footer {
    padding: 10px 0;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #bbb;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Please don't use ALL CAPS. Edited. Also changed tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't close the `.container` and `#content` divs. This might be the issue.